# Is there any difference between Chandas (meter) in Vedic and non-vedic literature

Tags: vedas

I am new to learning the RigVeda and have some formal education in Samskrita.

While going through the Veda, I could not comprehend the Chandas cited there.

The significant difference is that non-Vedic literature does not have Udatta, Anudatta, and Svarita.

Also, is there any online/offline tool to relook into the rik from Rig-veda for my understanding? I know some tools available to check the chandas for non-Vedic literature.

Regards - Anil

Comment: So, if I can understand properly, are you asking for sources to learn the chandas (meters) used in the hymns of R̥g Veda? Or do you just want to know the name of the chandas used for each hymn?

Comment: @Bingming I was trying to fit in some of the chandas mentioned in the Rigveda from what I learned in Samskrita class. I found it challenging to fit it, as Rigveda has Udatta, Anudatta, and Svarita. Now, I want to know, how to assign Laghu and Guru for these characters. The chandas names for the majority of the Rik's are with me.

Comment: udātta, anudātta, svarita are pitch accents, they aren't chandas (meters).  
So, according to me you are just confusing them wrongly with chandas. 
Check https://learnsanskrit.org/ends/sounds/accent/ and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_accent

Comment: Here are some good videos to help in learning about accents more: 
Vedic accents 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PdeMTp1Rko ;
Vedic accents 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqBOnq-Mn0c ; 
Vedic accents 3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9ZG6OxNQ40 ; 
Vedic accents 4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTB3LC-7H3g ;
And yes, you are right, pitch accents aren't used in non-Vedic lit. or later lit. that much, it's not common to see them there.

Comment: @Bingming As far as I Understand, dirgha swara should be labeled as Guru and Hrasva should be labeled as Laghu (depending on the time taken). In the case of some swarita, the time taken is twice that of udatta. Therefore, what should we consider at these places, laghu or guru?

Comment: I am not sure if svarita is determined as laghu or guru, because it's a mix of udātta and anudātta

Comment: basically, you just see the syllable and see whether its laghu or guru, not the pitch accent.

Comment: Ok. Noted. Will go through the Youtube videos shared and analyze them once again. Thanks for the help offered.

Comment: like perhaps if we have *kà*, according to me, this must be a laghu syllable, despite of the svarita accent. Accent is basically the way you chant, there is no laghu svarita or guru svarita according to me. But the syllable which is accented, is instead guru or laghu.

Comment: I don't think I could help much, but I tried 